# [Swift]How do I initialize a class expecting a String with a ReadLine?

Tags: swift, string, class, option-type, init

I'm learning swift and I'm trying to initialize a Player object by passing it name String defined by user input but I have to unwrap it and unwrapping it throws and error. It's an assignment so I don't think Im allowed to changed the parameter in Player to a String optional. Is there a way to make this work? If so how?

```
class PlayGame{
private var player:Player

public init(){
   
print("Welcome, please enter your name: ")
    if let str = readLine()
    {
        self.player = Player(name:str)
    }
}
```

}
Currently getting a 'Return from initiazlizer without initializing all stored properties'

```
class Player{
private var name:String

public init(name:String)
{
    self.name = name
}
```

this is what I'm trying and its failing

Comment: Are there any other properties besides `name` inside `Player`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
public init(){

    print("Welcome, please enter your name: ")
    if let str = readLine()
    {
        self.player = Player(name:str)
    }
}
```

If "str" is "nil" then the player is not initialized

I did fix it

```
public init(){
    print("Welcome, please enter your name: ")
    if let str = readLine()
    {
        self.player = Player(name:str)
    } else {
        player = Player(name:"default")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can use "nil coalescing operator" (also called "default operator").

```
class PlayGame {
    private var player: Player

    public init() {
        print("Welcome, please enter your name: ")
        let str = readLine() ?? "unnamed"
        self.player = Player(name: str)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense, I wish I could make both responses as being the correct answer